# SELECT: Combine value of two or more select and get their combination as output

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I having lots of days googling with this problem and I have got nothing. I need to make a SELECT that DUPLICATE and DUPLICATE and DUPLICATE depends upon the user. After that I need to combined the value of every options in a select that I selected. I hope that I've got an answer here. The following codes below:

```
<button name="duplicateselect" class="btn btn-primary">ADD ANOTHER SELECT</button>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select1">ELEMENT 1</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
        <option value="H">HYDORGEN</option>
        <option value="O">OXYGEN</option>
        <option value="K">POTASSIUM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select2">ELEMENT 2</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
        <option value="H">HYDORGEN</option>
        <option value="O">OXYGEN</option>
        <option value="K">POTASSIUM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Combination Here" name="combination" id="combination">
</div>
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:
e.g. I selected at select1 **HYDROGEN** and at select2 **OXYGEN**
value should be **H + O**

Answer (score 2):

You have two `select` with id `select2`. You need to change one of them. Try the following:

```js
$('input[name=duplicateselect').click(function(){
    var sel1 = $('#select2 option:selected').val();
    var sel2 = $('#select3 option:selected').val();
    $('#combination').val(sel1+' + '+sel2)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="duplicateselect" class="btn btn-primary">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select1">ELEMENT 1</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
        <option value="H">HYDORGEN</option>
        <option value="O">OXYGEN</option>
        <option value="K">POTASSIUM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select2">ELEMENT 2</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select3">
        <option value="H">HYDORGEN</option>
        <option value="O">OXYGEN</option>
        <option value="K">POTASSIUM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Combination Here" name="combination" id="combination">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, eureka. But sir I forgot that I need that it should be automatically combine and it should duplicate duplicate when i click duplicate. But @Mamun , that right.

Comment: Do you want the value to be calculated on change of the options?

Comment: that may mean you just want $('#combination').val($('#combination').val() + sel1+' + '+sel2)

Comment: @Andiih, the requirements here is not 100% clear to me.

Comment: @Mamun I'm looking like  this one one sir http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion.  But  in my case I need a select not input and combine value automatically like the answer of SESN at https://codepen.io/SESN/pen/bqyexN?editors=1111.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to require some simple javascript (or jQuery). There are a couple of options depending on how you want it to behave:

A) Add an onchange event handler to the select boxes. When either of them change take the value and pop it into the combination box

B) Add an obsubmit event handler for the form which does the same thing - here the final #combination would only be populated on submit, rather than on change

(As an answer has just popped up from @mamun I'll not bother retyping the code!)

Comment: Okay, sir I need a codes that duplicate that select and add that value in my input

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
  var s = '';
  $('select').each(function(){
    if(s == '') {
      s = $(this).val();
    } else {
      s = s + ' + ' + $(this).val() ;  
    }
  })
  $('#combination').val(s);
})
```

https://codepen.io/SESN/pen/bqyexN?editors=1111

Comment: Yes, you've got it. but need the select will be increase and descrease. Its called CLONED OR APPEND I think, something like that.

Comment: Okay, I've got it. It's too complicated but I think you've give me a help!! @Ronin Cypis

Comment: @Ronin Cypis, I have edited the solution. let me know if there is any other way to optimize the solution

Comment: @SESN , in the answer you optimize is there can duplicate the select??